# Can you generate html locally, without using a server?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show images in a local html file using a loop. This is what I want it to show in the web browser:

```
<div id="polybridges">
    <img src="polybridge_1.gif">
    <img src="polybridge_2.gif">
    <img src="polybridge_3.gif">
    <img src="polybridge_4.gif">
    <img src="polybridge_5.gif">
</div>
```

This is my attempt to do this with javascript:

```
<script>
    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var elem = document.createElement("img");
        elem.src='polybridge_'+i+'.gif';
        document.getElementById("polybridges").appendChild(elem);
    }
</script>
<div id="polybridges">
```

This doesn't generate anything. Is there a way to show images in a loop without using a server / localhost?

Comment: put your images in the same directory as your html file.

Comment: Put the div tag before the script or have your function run onload. Append the element instead of a string

Comment: What about AppendChild(elem)?

Comment: @malix: It's `appendChild`, and the OP is using it.

Comment: I know, typing on my iPhone put a capital, I'm saying the OP is appending a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first your element must be defined before script execution (so change the order). I suppose you want to append `elem` (instead of `"hallo"` string):

```
<div id="polybridges"></div>
<script>
    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var elem = document.createElement("img");
        elem.src='polybridge_'+i+'.gif';
        document.getElementById("polybridges").appendChild(elem);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Oh oops haha yeah i kept that in there, i was trying if i could set the text in the div but that didn't work either and i forgot to put the "hello" back.

Answer (score 2):

Put your images in the same directory as your html file.

```
 for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var elem = document.createElement("img");
        elem.src='polybridge_'+i+'.gif';
        document.getElementById("polybridges").appendChild(elem);
    }
```

And change the argument for `appendChild`.

Answer (score 1):

As malix states in his comment, you should use `document.getElementById("polybridges").appendChild(elem);` instead of `document.getElementById("polybridges").appendChild("hallo");` (so append the element instead of string "hallo").

And, as the rest states, the images should be where you tell the browser they are.

Comment: Sorry, I read over that. I forgot to place the elem back after trying to set the text to a string to test if that worked.

Comment: The problem was that I tried accessing the div before i declared it. See madox2's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can display images without server, you have to have that images in same directory as your html file or in `images` folder which in same level as your html file ( for that case images would be available as `<img src="images/polybridge_5.gif">`

Answer (score 0):

[appendChild](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) take Node as parameter (not string)

```
    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var elem = document.createElement("img");
        elem.src='polybridge_'+i+'.gif';
        document.getElementById("polybridges").appendChild(elem);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of one thing. You are trying to get element by ID. So you need to make sure that html is valid. Provide proper **close tag** for the element. Also use the `elem` variable in the `appendChild()`.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  var elem = document.createElement("img");
  elem.src = 'polybridge_' + i + '.gif';
  console.log(elem)
  document.getElementById("polybridges").appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="polybridges"></div>
```